# Bukkit Wait/Delay help (Bukkit Runnable)

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm having a bit of trouble with using a bukkit runnable. I've tried to get it to work, but it just throws errors at me. Here's what I'd like

```
public class FlyE implements Listener {

  @EventHandler
  public void onPlayerMovement(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
      Player p = e.getPlayer();
      double y1 = p.getLocation().getY();
      // wait 1 second
      double y2 = p.getLocation().getY();
      double yf = y1 - y2;
      Bukkit.broadcastMessage(p + " Increase = " + yf);   

  }
}
```

This code is intended to get a users Y coords, wait a second, get it again, and then work out the increase. However, no matter how I attempt to use the BukkitRunnable, it just confuses me. I was hoping somebody could walk me through how to convert the below into a Bukkit Runnable that gathers y1, waits 20 ticks, then gathers y2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The player move event is called every time the player moves. You only need to start a Bukkit scheduler once and then it will run continuously. I'm not sure how you want to select your player so this might not be exactly what you want to achieve, but to start a scheduler once put it in the onEnable() method.

```
public class MyPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> lastY = new HashMap<>(); //Stores the last y location for an arbitrary number of users. The map key (String) is the user's name and the value (Integer) is the user's last Y coord

    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        //Start the timer asynchronously because it doesn't need to run on the main thread and the time will also be more accurate
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimerAsynchronously(this, new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) { //Loop through all the players on the server
                    int y = player.getLocation().getBlockX();
                    player.sendMessage("Increase = " + (y - lastY.getOrDefault(player.getName(), 0))); //Display the increase in height using the stored value or 0 if none exists
                    lastY.put(player.getName(), y); //Replace their previous y coordinate with the new one
                }
            }

        }, 0, 20L);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerQuit(PlayerQuitEvent e){
        lastY.remove(e.getPlayer().getName()); //Remove stored data for player
    }

}
```

The HashMap here allows you to store the y coordinate for all the players on the server and access them in an efficient way. However, remember to remove the stored data when it is no longer needed (i.e. the player quits the game)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed :D